# Replace every element by sum of all other elements

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, python-3.5

I have to replace every element in the list by sum of all other elements in the list.

```
[1, 2, 3] => [5, 4, 3]
[1] => [0]
[2, 7, 9] => [16, 11, 9]
```

I have done so far:

```
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    numbers[i] = sum[numbers[:i]] + sum[numbers[i+1:]]
return numbers
```

But I'm keep getting `TypeError`

Comment: Multiple issues here. `return` outside of function, altering the list you're using to sum, square brackets when calling. It might be you're coming from another language? Either way, take a tour of the Python docs (see [Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)) when you can, it would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elegant way to achieve this will be:

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> [sum(my_list)-x for x in my_list]
[5, 4, 3]
```

OR, even better to calculate `sum` outside the *list comprehension* so that you won't have to calculate it each time (as pointed by *@Jean*):

```
>>> my_sum = sum(my_list)
>>> [my_sum-x for x in my_list]
[5, 4, 3]
```

---

**Issue with your code:** You are not making call `()` to `sum`, instead trying to access it's index using `[..]` resulting in `TypeError`. Also, you are modifying the original list while iterating which will result in different result (which is unexpected result for you). You should be placing these values in separate list.

Comment: note that this solution recomputes the sum at each iteration. This should be stored in a variable to avoid that.